# Is there documentation mapping matplotlib's stateful pyplot API to the object-oriented equivalents?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I prefer to use Matplotlib's object-oriented API, operating on figures and axes directly, rather than use `matplotlib.pyplot` commands.

However I often find it easier to find documentation on how to do something via the `pyplot` interface. In these cases it would be really useful to find out what the relevant `pyplot` commands are doing in terms of Figure and Axes methods, as it would help me handle whatever specific corner case I was wrestling with when I went looking for documentation.

For instance, `plt.xlabel()` is equivalent to `ax.set_xlabel()` if `ax` is the "current" axes in pyplot's stateful interface. But I can't find anything in the `xlabel()` documentation that mentions `Axes.set_xlabel()` at all. In this case it's not too hard to look up separately in the Axes documentation, but a mapping would be really nice.

Is there any source of information that would tell me what each particular `pyplot` command does in terms of the object-oriented interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the source, Luke! Many pyplot commans are just very thin wrappers around `Axes` or `Figure` methods. I usually use IPython.

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: plt.xlabel??
Signature: plt.xlabel(s, *args, **kwargs)
Source:
def xlabel(s, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Set the *x* axis label of the current axis.

    Default override is::

      override = {
          'fontsize'            : 'small',
          'verticalalignment'   : 'top',
          'horizontalalignment' : 'center'
          }

    .. seealso::

        :func:`~matplotlib.pyplot.text`
            For information on how override and the optional args work
    """
    return gca().set_xlabel(s, *args, **kwargs)
File:      ~\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py
```

Comment: Great idea! I'm usually in Jupyter anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I would say there are four classes of `pyplot` commands in terms of potential OO API commands.

1. Direct equivalents: All plotting functions simply have their equivalent in the `matplotlib.axes.Axes` class, e.g. `plt.plot` > `ax.plot`.  All auxilary functions have their equivalent in the `matplotlib.figure.Figure` class, e.g. `plt.colorbar` > `fig.colorbar`, `plt.subplots_adjust` > `fig.subplots_adjust`
2. Plot attributes have a getter and setter in the axes class, e.g. `plt.title` > `ax.set_title`
3. Some pyplot commands do not have any eqivalent, e.g. `plt.subplots` or `plt.show`
4. Some commands are just available in the pyplot namespace and would need to be imported from the respective submodule for OO interfacing, e.g. `plt.Normalize` > `import matplotlib.colors; matplotlib.colors.Normalize`.

Usually searching for a function or command brings up both variations. One may also explicitely look into the [figure](https://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html) or the [axes](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html) documentation to find the command. Finally, the [source of matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib) is available and one can look into the [pyplot code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py) to which API function is called for a given pyplot command.