# How does matplolib knows on which figure to plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to understand how matplotlib works (my question is probably more general though).

To plot a curve, I can do either of the following:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
plt.plot([1,2,3])
#%%
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,2,3])
```

In the first case, python knows that the plot should be done with respect to the set of axes "ax". In the second case I "tell it" in a way that it is for the set of axes "ax" because I use the method from ax.

**First question:**

How does the first way works ? How does python knows that the plot has to be done with ax ? What is the mechanics behind this ? Indeed I would expect that I have to tell it on what to plot. But it "deduces" it.

**Second question:**

As a related question: is there anything different between the two ways of plotting or are they totally equivalent ?

**Third question:**

plt.plot has an "analog method" with the axes: ax.plot

plt.pcolor has an "analog method" with the axes: ax.pcolor

We can find many other examples for that.

Is it true for all plotting method ? Inside of matplotlib is it indeed exactly the same code behind plt.FUNCTION and ax.FUNCTION (using the same "FUNCTION" for both)?

Comment: Matplotlib provides two interfaces as described here [Is there documentation mapping matplotlib's stateful pyplot API to the object-oriented equivalents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209062/is-there-documentation-mapping-matplotlibs-stateful-pyplot-api-to-the-object-or) and in the Matplotlib [API documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/index.html).

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but as far as I know, `plt.` just calls the method `gca()` which just calls the last ax you interacted with and then applies the function you called to that axis.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one plot, then plotting using plt.plot or ax.plot makes no difference. However if you have multiple plots as shown below:

[image: Multiple plots]

Then if you use plt.plot, it will plot only on the top left subplot by default. So if you want to plot, e.g. on the bottom right subplot, you must define the axes on which to plot. Then you must use ax. See: *[Plot multiple plots in Matplotlib](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/plot-multiple-plots-in-matplotlib/)*

So, if you have one plot, there is not difference between plt and ax. While if you have multiple plots or you are using FuncAnimation then it is better to use ax.